# JpaRepository MySQL get the value of the string is null

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

In Service

When I use print the keys that output null

but  print the ids that is correct

please tell me why

I'm sure the database has data

orderBean

```
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "`Order`")
public class OrderBean {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String orderNumber;

    private String account;


    public String getOrderNumber() {
        return orderNumber;
    }

    public void setOrderNumber(String orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }
    //Getters and Setter ....

}
```

orderDAO

```
public interface OrderDAO extends JpaRepository<OrderBean, Long>{

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE account=?", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<OrderBean> findOrderByAccount(String account);
}
```

orderService

```
public List<OrderBean> findOrderByAccount(String account) {

List<OrderBean> orderBeanList = orderDAO.findOrderByAccount(account);

for(OrderBean orderBean : orderBeanList) {
            
String key = orderBean.getOrderNumber();
//output:null   null
String id = orderBean.getId();
//output:1   2
}
```

[image: DataBase]

Comment: Are you sure that the orderNumber is not null in the DB ?

Comment: I am very sure that the orderNumber is not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Query.

```
@Query("value = "SELECT * FROM `Order` WHERE account=?1", nativeQuery = true")
public List<OrderBean> findOrderByAccount(String account);
```

you can also try to change the Table name from `Order` to just Order

orderService

```
public List<OrderBean> findOrderByAccount(String account) {

List<OrderBean> orderBeanList = orderDAO.findOrderByAccount(account);
String id = "";
String key = "";
for(OrderBean orderBean : orderBeanList) {
            
  key = orderBean.getOrderNumber();
// or you can try System.out.println(orderBean.getOrderNumber);
//output:null   null
  id = orderBean.getId();
// or you can try System.out.println(orderBean.getId);
//output:1   2
}
```

try this it might solve your error.

Comment: still doesn't work, getId() is work, but getOrderNumber() is null

Comment: can you send the error

Comment: no error message,
just
WARN ： JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore , database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning

Comment: Have you change anything else apart from the code which I gave you ?

Comment: `
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE account=?1", nativeQuery = true)
 public List<OrderBean> findOrderByAccount(String account);
`
I change this.

But the order is a keyword in MySQL ,so it must be wrapped with ``

Comment: Ok so Change it to Order then I think it will work

Comment: Try this @Table(name = "Order") capitalize the O

Comment: Change it to Order is still not work

Comment: But I drop the table and create a new one named c_order , and it changed the column name orderNumber to order_number by itself , and it is work , but I don't know why ?

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at this [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query#2-native-2), it looks like query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM OrderBean ob WHERE ob.account=?1
```

Comment: still doesn't work, getId() is work, but getOrderNumber() is null

Comment: Can you update code examples to show how the code looks now?

Comment: ```@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE account=?1", nativeQuery = true)
 public List<OrderBean> findOrderByAccount(String account);
```
only modified here,
 like my other DAO code

Comment: In this query you have used `order` have you changed it to order as i have mentioned in my answer above

Comment: But the order is a keyword in MySQL ,so it must be wrapped with ``